# How to apply box-shadow on all four sides?

Tags: css, box-shadow

I'm trying to apply a `box-shadow` on all four sides. I could only get it on 2 sides:

[image]

Comment: CSS3please.com is always helpful for this kind of stuff...

Answer (score 199, accepted):

It's because of x and y offset. Try this:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff;
```

edit (year later..): Made the answer more cross-browser, as requested in comments :)

btw: there are many css3 generator nowadays..
[css3.me](http://www.css3.me/), [css3maker](http://www.css3maker.com/box-shadow.html), [css3generator](http://css3generator.com/) etc...

Comment: +1 because you got the right answer faster, although it does look better with a smaller radius and a spread value.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking at your first answer and thought, that I got the question wrong :)

Comment: you should make your answer more cross-browser.

Comment: I am not sure why, but this does not work for me.  I get no box shadow when I use this.  If I use the answer posted by @thirtydot then it works.  You have to have the blur and spread if the first two values are 0.  This is happening in Chrome.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams: This answer does work, you probably just can't quite see the white box shadow. Here's a red version, should be more obvious: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/tcy8w0fq/1/

Comment: @thirtydot - You are right, with a lighter background, you can see it.  But if your background is black you cannot see it at all. So I guess I shouldn't say it doesn't work.  But it definitely is not visible without the spread when you have a black background, regardless of the color of the box-shadow.  Even with red it appears your border is slightly red, but there is no "visible" box shadow.  So if you have a lighter background, then I guess this solution would work.  For a very dark background, this solution is not reliable. http://jsfiddle.net/vkzd71rc/ vs http://jsfiddle.net/vkzd71rc/1/

Comment: @Damb by just using blur-radius the shadow will not spread evenly on corners, we have to use the spread-radius as well to make sure the shadow is same on all the 4 side of container including the 4 corners as well, so better to use ```box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px #fff``` for more info can refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

Answer (score 40):

See: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/cMNX2/8/

```
input {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #fff;
}
```

Comment: I know what each value is for in box shadow with 3 value + color. what is this 4 value stands for??

Comment: Read: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Box-shadow - specifically, it's the "spread radius".

Comment: Fiddle creator - MVP.

Answer (score 22):

Just simple as this code:

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px black; /*any color you want*/
```

Answer (score 12):

Understand box-shadow syntax and write it accordingly

```
box-shadow: h-offset v-offset blur spread color;
```

h-offset: Horizontal offset of the shadow. A positive value puts the shadow on the right side of the box, a negative value puts the shadow on the left side of the box - Required

v-offset: Vertical offset of the shadow. A positive value puts the shadow below the box, a negative value puts the shadow above the box - Required

blur: Blur radius (The higher the number, the more blurred the shadow will be) - Optional

color: Color of the shadow - Optional

spread: Spread radius. A positive value increases the size of the shadow, a negative value decreases the size of the shadow - Optional

inset: Changes the shadow from an outer shadow to an inner shadow - Optional

```
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #999;
```

box-shadow works better with spread

```
box-shadow: 0 0 10px 8px #999;
```

use 'inset' to apply shadow inside of the box

```
box-shadow: 0 0 8px inset #999;
(or)
box-shadow: 0 0 8px 8px inset #999;
```

use rgba (red green blue alpha) to adjust the shadow more efficiently

```
box-shadow: 0 0 8px inset rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.8); 
(or)
box-shadow: 0 0 8px 8px inset rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.8);
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp

Answer (score 10):

This looks cool.

```
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999;
```

Answer (score 5):

The most simple solution and easiest way is to add shadow for all four side. CSS

```
box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #ccc; /* with blur shadow*/
box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #ccc; /* without blur shadow*/
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/how-to-add-shadows-on-all-4-sides-of-a-block-with-css/ site.

```
.allSides
{
    width:350px;height:200px;
    border: solid 1px #555;
    background-color: #eed;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
```

Comment: it is appropriate as the other answers in this site, but as you are striving, i am up voting your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just simple as this:

```
box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px rgb(186 195 78), -3px -3px 5px rgb(186 195 78);
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 4px #000;
```

Where:

- The first 2 values are the `offset-x` and `offset-y` of the shadow
- The 3rd value - `blur radius`
- The 4th value - `spread radius`

Else, you can generate a box-shadow online, using [CSS box shadow generator](https://css-box-shadows.com/css-box-shadow-generator/)

Answer (score 1):

## CSS3 box-shadow: 4 sides symmetry

> 1. each side with the same color

```css
:root{
  --color: #f0f;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.four-sides-with-same-color {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px var(--color);
}
```

```html
<div class="four-sides-with-same-color"></div>
```

> 2. each side with a different color

```css
:root{
  --color1: #00ff4e;
  --color2: #ff004e;
  --color3: #b716e6;
  --color4: #FF5722;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,0,0.7);
}

.four-sides-with-different-color {
  box-shadow: 
    10px 0px 5px 0px var(--color1),
    0px 10px 5px 0px var(--color2),
    -10px 0px 5px 0px var(--color3),
    0px -10px 5px 0px var(--color4);
}
```

```html
<div class="four-sides-with-different-color"></div>
```

### screenshots

[image]

[image]

### refs

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-shadow/

https://www.cnblogs.com/xgqfrms/p/13264347.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this css code for all four sides: 
box-shadow: 0px 1px 7px 0px rgb(106, 111, 109);

Answer (score 0):

You can different combinations at the following link.
https://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow

The results which you need can be achieved by the following CSS

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using (v1)px (v2)px (v3)px (v4)px as an example.
v1px when positive gives right side shadow whiles negative value gives left side shadow.
v2px when positive gives top side shadow whiles negative value gives bottom side shadow.
v3 is used for making the shadow blur. 10px will make shadow more blur than 5px and so on
So using a div (mydiv) with style below. We will get the image below

```
box-shadow:
30px 0px 5px 0px red,
0px 30px 5px 0px blue,
-30px 0px 5px 0px green,
0px -30px 5px 0px yellow;
width:200px;
height:200px;
margin-left:100px;
}

<br><br>

<div class="mydiv"></div>

This should give you the div below
view the result from this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUjRN.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your box style.

```
box-shadow: 0 0 0 width color;
```

as example:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px yellow;
```

You can find more details here [MDN Web Docs - Setting zero for offset and blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow#setting_zero_for_offset_and_blur)

Answer (score 0):

Make the x and y offsets negative to apply the shadows on left and top sides of the container as well.

`div { box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #BDBDBD, -1px -1px 1px 1px #BDBDBD; }`

In the above code block,

1. `1px 1px 1px 1px #BDBDBD` is for adding shadows to the right and bottom sides.
2. `-1px -1px 1px 1px #BDBDBD` is for adding shadows to the top and left sides.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with Seshu Vuggina. Using box-shadow (specifically with *inset*) produces a great effect.
https://codepen.io/don199/pen/abMLpLY

[image]

dragonfly
</div

```
.container{
  width: 100vw;
}  
.button {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px #595959;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(166,166,166,1) 0%,   rgba(204,204,204,1) 50%, rgba(166,166,166,1) 100%);
    border: solid #b3b3b3 2px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #ddd;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
  }
```